# Prove by induction: $n(2n^2 − 3n + 1)$ is divisible by 6 for any n ∈ N

Tags: induction, divisibility

After a basis of n=1 and the induction step I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: $n$ is even or $2n^2-3n+1$ is; $n$ or $2n-1$ or $n-1$ is divisible by $3$

Comment: If you factor it you have $n(2n-1)(n-1)$.  If you replace $n$ with $n+1$ you get $(n+1)(2n+1)n$ or $n(2n+1)(n+1)=n(2n-1)(n+1) + 2n(n+1)=n(2n-1)(n-1)+ 2n(2n-1) + 2n(n+1)=n(2n-1)(n-1)+ 6n^2$.  If we assume $n(2n-1)(n-1)$ is divisible by $6$ then $n(2n-1)(n-1)+ 6n^2$ is too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f(n) = n(2n^2 - 3n +1) = 2n^3 - 3n^2 + n$ is divisible by $6$ for $n=k$

Let $f(k) = 6m$ for an integer $m$

Now $$f(k+1) - f(k) = 2(k+1)^3 - 3(k+1)^2 + (k+1) - (2k^3 - 3k^2 + k) = 6k^2$$
Or, $$f(k+1) = f(k) + 6k^2 = 6(m + k^2) = 6n$$ where $n ~ (= m+k^2)$ is an integer.

Hope you can do the rest!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume that $n(2n^2 − 3n + 1)$ is divisible by $6$ up to some $n$.  Then consider the expression with $n+1$: $$(n+1)(2(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) + 1).$$  Try to manipulate the expression so that you end up with $$n(2n^2 − 3n + 1) + \text{expression clearly divisible by }6.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without induction. Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \in \mathbb{N},\tag{$\ast$}$$meaning that $6$ divides  $n(2n^2+3n+1)$. However, we also have that $$n(2n^2-3n+1) = n(2n^2+3n+1) - 6n^2,$$so $6$ must divide $n(2n^2-3n+1)$ as well.

---

Proof of $(\ast)$ without induction: start with $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^3 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 + 3\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^n1$$and do a change of variable $k+1 \mapsto k$ on the left hand side to obtain

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 + (n+1)^3 - 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^3+3\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n,$$cancel the sum of cubes and solve for the sum of squares in one shot. One can also prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$ with the same strategy, starting from $\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)^2$.

Comment: in fact, $6\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2=n(2n^2-3n+1)$

Comment: Great! Even easier.

Comment: You probably would prove the formula for $\sum k^2$ with *induction*

Comment: Not really. I added a proof for that formula without induction too.